# How to silently install ASP.NET 2.0 Ajax extension 1.0?

Tags: powershell

I would like to silently install ASP.NET 2.0 Ajax extension 1.0 with a powershell script on Windows OS and I did not find anything on internet.

Comment: by silently, you mean that without doing any impact analysis?

Comment: i mean no user interface or interaction